# Map keeps assigning last value to all keys

Tags: arrays, flutter, sorting

I need to put same list in single key but map keeps putting the last value in the keys
Ex: I have [a,a,a,a,b,b,b,b,b] and I want {[a,a,a,a],[b,b,b,b,b]}

```
Map listStatus = {};
List<Status> stats = [];

@override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    setupListStatus();
  }

   setupListStatus() {
    for (var i = 0; i < widget.status.length; i++) {
      if (i == 0 ||
          widget.status[i].authorId != widget.status[i - 1].authorId) {
        setState(() {
          stats.clear();
        });
      }
      setState(() {
        stats.add(widget.status[i]);
      });

      if (i == widget.status.length - 1 ||
          widget.status[i].authorId != widget.status[i + 1].authorId) {
        setState(() {
          listStatus[listStatus.length] = stats;
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the [collection package](https://pub.dev/packages/collection/install) to do all of the grouping logic for you, rather than writing all that code yourself and having to maintain it down the road.

First, import the collection package

```
import "package:collection/collection.dart";
```

Also, I recommend being more explicit with your typing, this will help your compiler and IDE:

```
Map<String, List<Status>> listStatus = {};
```

Then, use the `groupListsBy` method, like so (I assume based on your code, `authorId` is the correct thing to group by:

```
setupListStatus() {
  listStatus = widget.status.groupListsBy((element) => element.authorId);
  print(widget.status);
  print(listStatus);
  listStatus.forEach((key, value) {
    print(key);
    value.forEach((element) { print( element.authorId);});
  });
}
```

Output:

```
flutter: [Instance of 'Status', Instance of 'Status', Instance of 'Status', Instance of 'Status', Instance of 'Status', Instance of 'Status', Instance of 'Status', Instance of 'Status']
flutter: {a: [Instance of 'Status', Instance of 'Status', Instance of 'Status', Instance of 'Status'], b: [Instance of 'Status', Instance of 'Status', Instance of 'Status', Instance of 'Status']}
flutter: a
flutter: a
flutter: a
flutter: a
flutter: a
flutter: b
flutter: b
flutter: b
flutter: b
flutter: b
```